# jQuery jHTMLArea character count

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build an interactive character left feature but I am having problems attaching it to jHTMLArea.

I am guessing this is because the plugin hides the actual textarea.

I tried Keith Woods character count but that didnt work.

Any suggestions on how to attach something like this to jHTMLArea?

Comment: It's possible it's using a `contenteditable` attribute on a `div` or something.

Comment: Take a look here: http://pietschsoft.com/demo/jHtmlArea/ and using Firebug or Chrome Console, inspect the element and take a look at the `onclick` handler for the `Alert HTML` button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That alert html button converts everything in the jHTMLArea. I still cant work out how to get a live count.

Comment: What about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5LkZn/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle events inside the editor with `$(mycontrol.jhtmlarea.editor.body)`

Capture the number of characters by doing something like this in the `loaded` callback of your `htmlarea` call:

```
$(".txtCustomHtmlArea").htmlarea({
    // Other properties here...
    loaded: function() {
        var mycontrol = { jhtmlarea: this };
        $(mycontrol.jhtmlarea.editor.body).on('keyup keypress blur change', function(e) {
            var charsPresent = $(this).text().length;
            $('#counter_box').val(charsPresent);
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to traverse the DOM to get your counter box, you can reference the jHtmlArea container with `$(mycontrol.jhtmlarea.container)`